# How do I launch/use Cygwin as the shell for TortoiseHg?

Tags: windows, shell, cygwin

In the settings for TortoiseHg, there is an option to select what shell you would like to use.  The two defaults listed are, as you might expect, "windows_command_prompt" and "powershell" but I would like to use Cygwin.  From the documentation: http://tortoisehg.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#tortoisehg
There is some help text...

> Specify the command to launch your preferred terminal shell
> application. If the value includes the string %(reponame)s, the name
> of the repository will be substituted in place of %(reponame)s.
> (restart needed)
>
> Default, Windows: cmd.exe /K title %(reponame)s
>
> Default, OS X: not set
>
> Default, other: xterm -T "%(reponame)s"

I know I can launch Cygwin normally from windows just like the shortcut does...

> C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -

And I figure I can add on extra options to adjust the title...

> C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -T "%(reponame)s" -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -

but when I set that as the shell, I get an error saying that TortiseHg is unable to start that command.

I can reduce the command to just...

> C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe

and it still doesn't work.

Is TortoiseHg adding on commands meant for Windows-style shells which wouldn't be compatible with Cygwin?

Is there a way to make Cygwin my shell for TortoiseHg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is needed in the "Shell" options line is `mintty`

I installed `chere`, which seems to have made a difference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637601/open-cygwin-at-a-specific-folder

I like putting the icon back, so it grows to `mintty -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico`

The title can be changed by adding back in the -T option (to the repo name `"%(reponame)s"` or the full path `"%(root)s"`).

I also had a `cd` command in my .bashrc file, so I had to get rid of that. (it would force the directory change every time bash was opened)